# How to find the limit of $f(x)$ when $\lim_{x\ \to \infty} xf(x)=2$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function
> such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x)=2$
>
> $1)$ Prove that there exists a $B_1>0$ such that $x > B_1 \Longrightarrow 1<xf(x)<3$
>
> $2)$ Using part $(1)$ calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$
> without using the definition of the limit. Deduce that there exists a
> $B_2>0$ such that $\forall x \in ]B_2,\infty[$ we have $|f(x)|\leq 1$.

My attempt:

For the first question, I simply stated the definition of a limit then set $\epsilon=1$ and got the result, my questions isn't about it but thought I'd include it as it might be relevant.

For part $2$, I used part $1$ as instructed and got for some $x>B_1$ we have that $\frac{1}{x}<f(x)<\frac{3}{x}$ as x goes to infinity both sides go to $0$ so by squeeze theorem the limit of $f(x)$ is $0$. Now here comes the problem, for the deduction part I tried stating the definition of the limit and setting $\epsilon=1$ but this gives $|f(x)|<1$ rather than $|f(x)|\leq 1$, made sure the question has no typos and it doesn't. This made me think I did something wrong previously which is why I am asking for help here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $|f(x)| < 1$, then $|f(x)| \le 1$ also.

Comment: I know that is logically correct but wouldn't the author ask directly for $|f(x)|<1$ then